# Что означает нотация `def setCoords(self, sp: Point, ep: Point):`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Объясните, пожалуйста, нотацию в данной программе.
Что означает к примеру `def setCoords(self, sp: Point, ep: Point):`?
Значит ли это, что в качестве атрибутов данного метода подаются экземпляры класса?
Я вот что-то не совсем понимаю как это происходит. Можно ли где-то об этом почитать?

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return f"({self.__x}, {self.__y})"

    def isDigit(self):
        if (isinstance(self.__x, int) or isinstance(self.__x, float)) and \
                (isinstance(self.__y, int) or isinstance(self.__y, float)):
            return True
        return False

    def isInt(self):
        if isinstance(self.__x, int) and isinstance(self.__y, int):
            return True
        return False


class Prop:
    def __init__(self, sp: Point, ep: Point, color: str = "red", width: int = 1):
        self._sp = sp
        self._ep = ep
        self._color = color
        self._width = width

    def setCoords(self, sp: Point, ep: Point):
        if sp.isDigit() and ep.isDigit():
            self._sp = sp
            self._ep = ep
        else:
            print("Координаты должны быть числами")


class Line(Prop):
    def drawLine(self):
        print(f"Рисование линии: {self._sp}, {self._ep}, {self._color}, {self._width}")

    def setCoords(self, sp: Point, ep: Point):
        if sp.isInt() and ep.isInt():
            self.__sp = sp
            self.__ep = ep
        else:
            print("Координаты должны быть целочисленными")
```

Comment: Да, в качестве аргументов подаются экземпляры класса Point

Comment: Поправка: не подаются, а должны подаваться. Нотация исключительно для информации и на самом деле правильность аргументов не проверяется, можно передать что угодно.

Comment: Почитать можно тут https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо

```
def func(par):
```

возможно писать например

```
def func(par: int) -> str:
```

что значит, что *ожидаемый тип* (т.е. класс) параметра `par` есть `int` (целое число) и *ожидаемый тип значения, которое функция возвращает*, есть `str` (строка).

Питон сам *не проверяет, если это исполнено,* но это может быть полезно

- *для документации* (тоже для *автоматически генерированной документации* некоторыми программами, например [Sphinx](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_(%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8))),
- для генерирования предупреждений некоторыми программами для работы с Питоном, например [PyCharm](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm).

---

Значит, в вашей программе например в определении

```
def __init__(self, sp: Point, ep: Point, color: str = "red", width: int = 1):
```

- параметры `sp` и `ep` «хотят быть» экземплярами класса `Point`,
- ключевой параметр `color` типа `str` (строкой)
- и ключевой параметр `width` типа `int` (целым числом).

Для самого Питона эта команда имеет то  же самое значение как

```
def __init__(self, sp, ep, color="red", width=1):
```